# lodash implicit gives "_ is not a function" error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, lodash

When trying to use lodash as implicit it gives the error "_ is not a function"

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as _ from "lodash";

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  testImplicit(){

    try{
      _(["a", "b", "c"]).filter(itm => itm == "b")
      alert("ok")
    }
    catch(err){
      alert("error : " + err)
    }


  }

  testExplicit(){

    _.filter(["a", "b", "c"], itm => itm == "b")
    alert("ok")
  }


}
```

You can see an example at stackblitz here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zrxrru

Comment: You're getting that error because `_` isn't a function, it's an object containing a long list of functions.  The error message is accurate.  I did not downvote you, but if I had to make a guess, it's because (1) the error message is pretty clear, and (2) your code is not in your question, it is only linked off-site.

Comment: Thanks for commenting; but I'm trying to use lodash as in that article : https://mariusschulz.com/blog/implicit-function-chaining-in-lodash.  I'll add the code in description then

Comment: That article is 4 years old.  It's either out-of-date, or that was a mistake on their part.  I think the error message is a better source of information than some blog author.  You might try using a 4-yo version of the library if that style of chaining is what you're after, though I believe this is a mistake by the author of the blog.

Comment: @Amy Its also in lodash documentation.  https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#lodash.  Search for "_(value)" in the page.  Sorry I cannot make a direct link to it

Comment: Very interesting!  I've used Lodash for almost 5 years, and I did not know this syntax existed.  More interesting, I can use this syntax in my own projects, so I suspect it your issue results from the particular Lodash build in use.  It was (*apparently*) built without support for implicit chaining.

Comment: Glad you learned something out of it :)  But still don't understand why my implementation of lodash in my stackblitz project doesn't work with implicits :(

Comment: I think its probably the build you're using.  I don't think its complete; I can use it in my project, but I'm using the full build, not a modularized NodeJS build.  Lodash provides a wide variety of custom builds.  https://lodash.com/custom-builds

Answer (score 2):

Lodash's `_` is not a function, it is an object, just like the error message indicates.

You are only using Lodash in two places in your code, and only one of those places uses `_` as a function.  This line of your code:

```
_(["a", "b", "c"]).filter(itm => itm == "b")
```

should be:

```
_.filter(["a", "b", "c"], itm => itm == "b")
```

Answer (score 2):

the Lodash module contains `_` as a function. It needs to be accessed from the module the same way all other functions are used.

```
    import _ from "lodash";  // import all lodash functions
    _._(["data"]) // use the function
```

The examples online may import the function `_` on its own

```
    import { _ } from "lodash"; // import '_' function alone
    _(["data"]) // use the function
```

Here is the documentation

> '_' Creates a lodash object which wraps value to enable implicit
> method chain sequences. Methods that operate on and return arrays,
> collections, and functions can be chained together. Methods that
> retrieve a single value or may return a primitive value will
> automatically end the chain sequence and return the unwrapped value.
> Otherwise, the value must be unwrapped with _#value.